# Existe alguma maneira de apanhar o antes do "orientationchange"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Na minha aplicação mobile (programada em **JavaScript**), tenho uma função que é activada quando a orientação do ecrã é alterada.

```
  $( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) {
     ...
   }
```

Eu, mesmo antes dessa função ser activada, gostava de ter uma outra função para guardar valores e isso. Tipo:  `$( window ).before( "orientationchange",...`.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: Dá uma olhada a isto: https://github.com/evaldsurtans/jquery.beforeorientationchange